# Ninject.Extensions.Wcf.SelfHost with nuget?

Tags: ninject, nuget, ninject-extensions

I pulled the latest **Ninject.Extensions.Wcf** (3.0.0.5) from nuget but the

**NinjectWcfConfiguration** type used in the SelfHost example is not in that package?

Answer (score 1):

No it's not. It is in the `Ninject.Extension.Wcf.SelfHost` 3.0.2-unstable-x prerelease

Comment: Yeah I missed to set the filter to unstable in nuget manager :P

Comment: Hmm, adding that package does not add any references?

Comment: After I added Ninject.Extensions.Wcf.SelfHost I get Ninject.Web.Common, Ninject.Extensions.Wcf and Ninject referenced. None contains the SelfHosting classes? Somethign wrong with the Nuget package?